# Showing ProgressDialog on AsyncThread Android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I want to show a ProgressDialog when a call to a Web Service call is made, this is my code:

```
public class penAPIController extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Object>{

private View view;
private ProgressDialog dialog;

public penAPIController(View v)
{
    view = v;
}
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        this.dialog = new ProgressDialog(view.getContext());
        this.dialog.setMessage("Loading, Please Wait..");
        this.dialog.setCancelable(false);
        this.dialog.show();
    }
```

The dialog shows indeed but only after doInBackground is finished, I want to be able to show it while doInBackground is doing its job. And then hide it on PostExecute

onPostExecute:

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object obj)
        {
            //dialog.dismiss();
            myMethod(obj);
        }

    private Object myMethod(Object myValue)
    {
         //handle value 
         return myValue; 
    }
```

doInBackground:

```
@Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... objects)
        {
            if(objects.length < minNumberOfParams)
            {
                return null;
            }
            Object finalObject = null;
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String NAMESPACE = "http://...";
            String METHOD_LOGIN_NAME = "Login";
            String SOAP_LOGIN_ACTION = "http://...";
            String METHOD_RUNACTION_NAME = "RunAction";
            String SOAP_RUNACTION_ACTION = "http://...";
            String CLIENT = (String)objects[0];
            String APPLICATION = (String)objects[1];
            String USERNAME = (String)objects[2];
            String PASSWORD = (String)objects[3];
            String URL = (String)objects[4];
            String ACTION_NAME = (String)objects[5];
            ArrayList arrayParams = null;
            if(objects.length == (minNumberOfParams + 1))
            {
                arrayParams = (ArrayList)objects[6];//Build parameters xml from ActionParam array
            }
            String PARAMETERS = buildParametersXML(arrayParams);

            SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_LOGIN_NAME);

            //Client
            PropertyInfo propertyClient = new PropertyInfo();
            propertyClient.setName("client");
            propertyClient.setValue(CLIENT);
            propertyClient.setType(CLIENT.getClass());
            Request.addProperty(propertyClient);
            //Application
            PropertyInfo propertyApplication = new PropertyInfo();
            propertyApplication.setName("application");
            propertyApplication.setValue(APPLICATION);
            propertyApplication.setType(APPLICATION.getClass());
            Request.addProperty(propertyApplication);
            //Username
            PropertyInfo propertyUsername = new PropertyInfo();
            propertyUsername.setName("username");
            propertyUsername.setValue(USERNAME);
            propertyUsername.setType(USERNAME.getClass());
            Request.addProperty(propertyUsername);
            //Password
            PropertyInfo propertyPassword = new PropertyInfo();
            propertyPassword.setName("password");
            propertyPassword.setValue(PASSWORD);
            propertyPassword.setType(PASSWORD.getClass());
            Request.addProperty(propertyPassword);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            try
            {
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_LOGIN_ACTION, envelope);
                SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
                String token = response.toString();

                SoapObject RequestRun = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_RUNACTION_NAME);

                //Token
                PropertyInfo propertyToken = new PropertyInfo();
                propertyToken.setName("token");
                propertyToken.setValue(token);
                propertyToken.setType(token.getClass());
                RequestRun.addProperty(propertyToken);
                //Action Name
                PropertyInfo propertyAction = new PropertyInfo();
                propertyAction.setName("actionName");
                propertyAction.setValue(ACTION_NAME);
                propertyAction.setType(ACTION_NAME.getClass());
                RequestRun.addProperty(propertyAction);
                //Parameters
                PropertyInfo propertyParams = new PropertyInfo();
                propertyParams.setName("parameters");
                propertyParams.setValue(PARAMETERS);
                propertyParams.setType(PARAMETERS.getClass());
                RequestRun.addProperty(propertyParams);

                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelopeRun = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelopeRun.dotNet = true;
                envelopeRun.setOutputSoapObject(RequestRun);
                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransportRun = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                androidHttpTransportRun.call(SOAP_RUNACTION_ACTION, envelopeRun);
                SoapPrimitive responseRun = (SoapPrimitive)envelopeRun.getResponse();
                String result = responseRun.toString();
                finalObject = parseOutputXML(result);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return finalObject;
          }
```

Comment: so what's your problem? override onPostExecute and dismiss the dialog

Comment: Your code seems correct. Do you have a dialog.dismiss(); onPostExecute?

Comment: @blackbelt My problem is that the dialog only shows after doInBackground is completed, not While it's running

Comment: @ThomasKa I do have dismiss() on onPostExecute but that's irrelevant, the ProgressDialog only shows up after doInBackground is finished

Comment: you missed the @Override annotation

Comment: Same with the @Override annotation

Comment: post doInBackground and onPostExecute

Comment: How do you submit your async task? Do you block the UI thread with `AsyncTask.get()`?

Comment: this is how I submit it: 
obj = new penAPIController(view).execute().get();

Also with execute(parameters), it has the same behaviour

Comment: It's the `get()` that blocks the UI thread and prevents progress dialog from showing until the asynctask result is available. I'll post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, you are calling `get()` on the `AsyncTask`. This will block the submitting thread (main UI thread in your case) until the async task result is available, that is, `doInBackground()` returns.

Remove the call to `get()` and handle the completion e.g. in `onPostExecute()` or using a callback function.

Comment: You are absolutely right. However, now I find another problem, since the UI thread doesn't wait for the result, how can I wait until the result from the AsyncThread is available to carry on with my execution?

Comment: Generally, you shouldn't wait but let the app do other tasks while the  async task is executing in the background. But if you absolutely must, you can "block" the user interface with a progress dialog and resume other tasks in UI thread e.g. in async task's `onPostExecute()` or progress dialog's `OnDismissListener`.

Answer (score 1):

```
   private ProgressDialog progressDialog;   // class variable       

   private void showProgressDialog(String title, String message)
   {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        progressDialog.setTitle(""); //title

        progressDialog.setMessage(""); // message

        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);

        progressDialog.show();
   }
```

**onPreExecute()**

```
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        showProgressDialog("Please wait...", "Your message");
    }
```

**Check and dismiss onPostExecute() -**

```
    protected void onPostExecute() 
    {
        if(progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing())
        {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
     }
```

Comment: and in what that's different from the OP Code?